# Improve loading of checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, optimization

I'm developping a e-site. In my catalog, I've more 1600 articles. Articles appear in a tab with a checkbox at the right, so there is 1600 checkbox ...

My problem is it's too long to load the page (more 1 second in VS 2005, and IE take 15 seconds to build the page ...)

I've a foreach where I made checkbox :

```
CheckBox cbox = new CheckBox();
cbox.ID = "cbox." + i;
cbox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbox_CheckedChanged);
cbox.AutoPostBack = true;

celluleCBOX.Controls.Add(cbox);
```

Have you any ideas to improve performance ?

Thanks !

Comment: 1600 checkboxes is way too many for any human to comprehend. You should look into what you are actually trying to allow the user to do

Comment: Are you really really really showing the 1,600 articles and checkboxes in one page?

Comment: No, i've filters, but when I load the page, all articles was load and stored into a tab, but no display.

Comment: Why don't you build them by filter instead of loading all at once.

Comment: You can filter it on serverside and if the user want more, you can load it through ajax

Comment: you should wait until the user set the filters, otherwise, it will be as slow as you saw, or even more, also it is bad for the UX of your site, performance matters

Comment: Yes, I'll try this way tomorrow. I don't know why I don't use this solution first time. Thank you. I'll tell you if it works better. @MaximilianAst I don't know how use Ajax with asp ...

Comment: Here is a short explanation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/401903/AJAX-for-Beginners-Part-Understanding-ASP-NET-AJ 
But you don't have to use ajax, you can do post-backs as well.